# How to get all fields of a user defined type returned as string

Tags: c#, string

I would like to return all fields of an UDT (user defined type) as a string.

My UDT type looks like this:

```
public class MyPointF
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }

    public MyPointF(float x, float y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

I would like to use the type like this:

```
MyPointF point1 = new MyPointF(10, 20);
System.Console.WriteLine(point1);
```

The return of this code should look like this:

```
{10, 20}
```

Of course I need also access to `point1.X` and `point1.Y` as float values. Any hint how to solve this would be great.

Comment: override ToString() of PointF...

Comment: have you tried to add a method to your class that would do exactly that? and call it like point1.Print()...and print method would return the string the way you like it

Comment: If you don't want to use the `System.Drawing` assembly, at least check how the `PointF` struct is implemented in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/PointF.cs). It would be better to make it immutable, and it would be even better to make it an immutable struct. Apart from that, they also implemented various methods and operators which allow you to compare and add/subtract points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to [`override`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) the `ToString` method in your `PointF` class like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "{ " + X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ," + Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " }";
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, but is there no way to do it without calling a method?

Comment: @DominikAmrein *When you create a custom class or struct, you should override the `ToString` method in order to provide information about your type to client code.* If you don't override the `ToString` it returns the class name when you print it.

Comment: @DominikAmrein: if you're asking whether you need to explicitly call `ToString()` when passing to `System.Console.WriteLine`, then answer is *no*, `Console` will call the method automatically. It will also be called automatically whenever you try to concatenate the object with a string (i.e. `"" + point1`). What you need to do is override the method inside your class, which is what the guys from Microsoft [also had to do for their `System.Drawing.PointF` struct](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/PointF.cs,221,284).

Comment: @DominikAmrein Also check the link to MSDN to know more about overriding `ToString` that I just included in my answer.

Comment: I understand! This is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PointF point1 = new PointF(10, 20);
            System.Console.WriteLine(point1);
            Console.Read();

        }


    }
    public class PointF
    {
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }

        public PointF(float x, float y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "{ " + X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ," + Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " }";

        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not look nice if current culture uses a comma for the decimal separator, but, then again, Microsoft does the same thing in their implementation of `PointF`.

Comment: Well, I am just saying I would use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, but it's my opinion. If you are using the current culture, you can simplify the return expression using C#6 interpolated strings, i.e. `return $"{{{X}, {Y}}}"`. But again, it's subject to debate whether this is "simplified". :)